# PHP Echo back a form inside of a table cell

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is how I am echoing back a 'normal' table cell in PHP:

#### Code:

```
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Some cell data</td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

#### Attempt to echo a button within a cell:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><form action="insertdata.php?page=add" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" >
    <input type="submit" >
    </form>
    </td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

Thank you for any help, this is quite confusing to me. I am a beginner when it comes to PHP so please pardon any errors and feel free to kindly correct me wherever a correction is needed!

Comment: What is your actual question? HTML looks good to display a button within a table cell.

Comment: As an aside, PHP is a templating language. You don't need to litter the script with echo statements. You can just write plain HTML outside of the PHP tags.

Comment: @webbiedave That is true, but probably should be discouraged, as it makes code much less readable, and tends to result in messy markup and large documents being output because you end up with a lot of unecessary new-lines and general white space. Also, it encourages the use of `<?` and `<?=` short tags, which can be disabled (and are by default in new PHP installations). More than once I have had to do a huge find/replace on someone's code for exactly that reason...

Comment: When used in template context it should absolutely be encouraged. However, if it's in the context of classes that contain methods that output HTML, then it should be discouraged... but so should those methods! Designers shouldn't be charged with going into PHP classes looking for echo statements and having to mind the quotes. They should have easy to follow templates and only be saddled with viewing logic that is for display purposes.

Comment: I am reading data from a MYSQL database, so no I don't think I could do that ^.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either escape your double quotes `"` that appear inside your string surrounded by double quotes, or use a different quote style (i.e. single quotes `'`) to surround the string that contains the double quotes. It's actually made quite obvious what the problem is by the syntax highlighting on this site.

You could either do this:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><form action=\"insertdata.php?page=add\" method=\"post\">
    Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" >
    <input type=\"submit\" >
    </form>
    </td>";
echo "</tr>\n";
```

...or this...

```
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><form action="insertdata.php?page=add" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" >
    <input type="submit" >
    </form>
    </td>';
echo "</tr>\n";
```

I suggest you [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) thoroughly so you no what you can and can't legally do with strings in PHP.

As a side note, it is a bad idea to put new-line literals inside quoted strings, as it can lead to cross-platform compatibility wierdness. It's not really a problem with web output like this, but it's a bad habit to get into. You should either use `\r`,`\n` and `\r\n` as appropriate, or if you must put literals into the source code, use [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Remember that escape sequences like `\r\n` **are only interpolated in double quoted strings!!!**

Comment: Do I even need the '\n' in the tr?

Comment: No, but it's probably an idea to leave it in. All it achieves is making your HTML source more readable, but certainly while you're developing this is a good idea anyway. When your done, feel free to remove all the white space from your HTML, it will reduce the amount of data that is output and save on hosting bandwidth.